Error `redirect_uri is missing or too long` from IdentityServer4 in DockerContainer
Description of the situation:
I have a project with IdentityServer4. When I start everything locally, it works good.
The problem arises when I want to start all this in Docker Containers (DB, FrontEnd, BackEnd, IdentityServer) Using ReverseProxy Traefik.
I created certificates to use HTTPS.
If I execute "https://MyHost/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration" or "https://MyHost/auth/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks" from the Browser, everything works, I receive as a response the expected JSON. If I connect to the BackEndDockerContainer and execute these requests via curl -v to the IdentityServerDockerContainer, everything works correctly, the same response. All Requests are via HTTPS.
"RedirectUris": [
"https://MyHost/",
], is defined in IdentityServer/appsettings.json
Error
After entering the login and password and pressing LogIn, an error appears in the Identity server "ERR redirect_uri is missing or too long",
" "RedirectUri": null, "AllowedRedirectUris": ["https:.....",
although redirect_uri exists and is defined in BrowserNetwork
Traefik for Identity
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.identity-server.rule=Host(`MyHost`)  && PathPrefix(`/auth{regex:$$|/.*}`)" 
  - "traefik.http.routers.identity-server.entrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.identity-server.tls=true"

  - "traefik.http.routers.identity-server.middlewares=identity-server-stripprefix"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.identity-server-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/auth"

The problem is somewhere in the Traefik configuration, but it is not clear where. Do you have any ideas, what else can be tried?
Any idea is welcome.

Not sure about traffic, but I am working on a blog post, containerizing IdenttiyServer in dockre compose, and the code for it is found at https://github.com/tndataab/PublicBlogContent/tree/main/IdentityServer-in-Docker perhaps that code can give you some hints (final code folder) , I will start posting the multi-part blog post in 2 weeks time.

Did you solve the problem? My blog post I mentioned above is not published at https://nestenius.se/net/identityserver-in-docker-containers-part-1/   , perhaps it can help? Besides that, I would make an testing enpoint, that just mirrors back what it receives and then send a sample request to it and see what is passed through and what is filtered. Or to make it simple, redirect all the traffic to https://httpbin.org/#/Anything , it will mirror back what it receives.
